# sticky header move one pixel up when I block the scroll on body

Tags: css

It's a really weird problem I encounter on chrome mobile.

When you have a sticky header, using just position: sticky.
Scroll before the end of the page and then add a prevent scrolling on body with the css property

```
overflow: hidden
```

The sticky header will move 1px up. 
This issue happen with position fixed too.

I created a demo, try on Android Chrome: https://run.plnkr.co/tCOjTUgjURu5Q2J5/

Answer (score 0):

the solution to this issue seems incredibly weird too.

If you use:

```
overflow-y: hidden
```

to prevent the scroll,

this property will not cause the jump on sticky/fixed element